# How can I set the printer configuration settings for all excel workbooks in a folder to the same configuration using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, printing, printf

I have a large number of excel files in a folder the user has a specific print format configuration that is supposed to be applied to all sheets in all workbooks .

How can I apply a common print scheme to all of these files using powershell?

Comment: Maybe [How to set a default template in Excel](https://exceljet.net/articles/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-excel) is an option for you?

Comment: @Theo over 200 "FILES" could be workbooks could have single sheets - I need to apply a common scheme with Powershell - we can't open and adjust all files without intensive labor efforts.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that's how Excel works. You can create a default template, but this will only have effect on new excel files. Existing files can only be opened and manually set to use such a template..